# If there a way to always have a list of choice when pressing Ctrl+Space on Komodo Edit?

Tags: python, autocomplete, intellisense, komodoedit

I'm new to **Komodo Edit / Python**. I would like to know why Komodo gives me a list of word to autocomplete my current word sometimes while at other times, it gives me nothing or it auto completes my current word without asking me (even if there's multiple choices)

Is there a way to tell Komodo to ALWAYS give me a list of choice when pressing Ctrl+Space (like the Visual Studio's behavior ?)

```
def TestMethod():
    return 1
def TestSecondMethod():
    return 2

Test #It doesn't show me the intellisense

TestSecondMethod #When I press Ctrl+Space, it autocomplete
                 #(without asking me) my word by entering
                 #the name of the second method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Komodo (IDE or Edit) doesn't seems to have a very good Intellisense for Python so I ended up using PyCharm Community Edition and this IDE work like a charm.

It is easy to configure and the autocomplete always work and is fast to show (compared to Komodo's)

Komodo gives the possibility to change the behavior of the Ctrl+Space to use the Auto complete behavior but it still doesn't work the way I wanted because it doesn't always shows and when it does, it does it slowly

You can change your key bindings preferences with :

```
Edit > Preference > Editor > Key Bindings > 
    change the command "Editor : Trigger preceding AutoComplete list or CallTipe" key sequence to be "Ctrl + Space" 
    the Ctrl+Space is normally assigned to the "Code : Complete Word" command
```

But anyone who's using Python should definitly give a try to Pycharm.